# Erron on Heroku Login from Command Line

Tags: heroku, facebook-apps

I am getting this error when I am trying to login to Heroku from Command Line in Windows :
[image]

It's fine when I am loggin in through browser.

What should I do? or What is the problem behind this?

Comment: maybe a restrictive firewall in your network?

Comment: Any solution other than public network?

Comment: Open your Firewall to let the relevant connections through …?